# Pasar valor de una fila seleccionada de jtable a un jcombobox en java

Tags: java, mysql, jtable, combobox

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un `jtable` cargado de la BD y quiero seleccionar una fila, al presionar enter se me cargue un `JCombobox` que tengo en **otro** `JFrame` lo cual hago:

Evento al presionar enter

```
    if ((evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
                        int filaSelecionada = jTablaLocalidades.getSelectedRow();
                        if (filaSelecionada == -1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se selecciono ninguna fila");

                       }else{
                            Localidad localidad = new Localidad();  
                            localidad.setNombre(jTablaLocalidades.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 1).toString());
                            this.agregarCliente.jcboLocalidad.getModel().setSelectedItem(localidad.getNombre());
                            agregarCliente.setVisible(true);
                            this.dispose();
                        }
                    }
```

Se me llena el combo con el objeto que selecciono de la fila pero no me guarda, me sale

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Datos.Localidad
```

Al presionar el botón guardar, lo que me lleva a la linea

```
Localidad cboLocalidad = (Localidad)jcboLocalidad.getSelectedItem();
```

Si cambio a `this.agregarCliente.jcboLocalidad.getModel().setSelectedItem(localidad);`

me guarda pero no me guarda el **id** en mi BD, me guarda 0 en mi tabla de la BD me explico? Lo que necesito es guardar el objeto con el **id** de dicha localidad seleccionada.

Mi clase Localidad

```
    private int idlocalidad;
    private String nombre;
    private int codpostal;
    private String DDN;
    private int idprovincia;
    private int idzona;

    public Localidad() {
    }

    public Localidad(int idlocalidad, String nombre) {
        this.idlocalidad = idlocalidad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getIdlocalidad() {
        return idlocalidad;
    }

    public void setIdlocalidad(int idlocalidad) {
        this.idlocalidad = idlocalidad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getCodpostal() {
        return codpostal;
    }

    public void setCodpostal(int codpostal) {
        this.codpostal = codpostal;
    }

    public String getDDN() {
        return DDN;
    }

    public void setDDN(String DDN) {
        this.DDN = DDN;
    }

    public int getIdprovincia() {
        return idprovincia;
    }

    public void setIdprovincia(int idprovincia) {
        this.idprovincia = idprovincia;
    }

    public int getIdzona() {
        return idzona;
    }

    public void setIdzona(int idzona) {
        this.idzona = idzona;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }
```

Cargo el combo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void cboLocalidad(){
        DefaultComboBoxModel modelo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
        try {
            Connection miComando = AdministradorConfiguracion.obtenerComandoMySql();
            CallableStatement obtenerLocalidades = miComando.prepareCall("call obtener_localidades()");
            ResultSet rs = obtenerLocalidades.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {                
                modelo.addElement(new Localidad(rs.getInt("Nro"), rs.getString("Localidad")));
                jcboLocalidad.setModel(modelo);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cargar combo:\n"
                    + e, "Error en la operación", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Alguna idea de lo que estoy haciendo mal? Desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como no das excesivos datos imagino que tu clase Localidad se compone de un campo ID y un campo con el nombre de la localidad.

Seguramente cuando muestras los resultados en la tabla, solo muestras el nombre de la localidad y no sabes su ID asociado en la BBDD.

En el primer caso guardas una String

```
this.agregarCliente.jcboLocalidad.getModel().setSelectedItem(localidad.getNombre());
```

Y quieres transformarla a un objeto de tipo Localidad

```
Localidad cboLocalidad = (Localidad)jcboLocalidad.getSelectedItem();
```

Por tanto es normal el error.

Mientras en el segundo caso si que asignas un objeto localidad:

```
this.agregarCliente.jcboLocalidad.getModel().setSelectedItem(localidad);
```

Pero un objeto localidad que solo contiene el nombre y no el campo ID, te faltaria indicarselo en algún momento.

```
Localidad localidad = new Localidad();  
localidad.setNombre(jTablaLocalidades.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 1).toString());
```

Para no complicarte, lo mejor seria guardar el ID en el objeto buscándolo en la BBDD a partir del nombre de la localidad(esto podría ser malo en caso de que haya localidades con el mismo nombre en ese caso te recomiendo guardar en la tabla el ID como campo oculto para estar seguro de la localidad y asignarlo a localidad.ID).

Te recomiendo que implementes algo así tras hacer el localidad.setNombre(..)

```
 localidad.setID(buscarIDenBBDD(localidad.getNombre());
```

Comment: efectivamente, tengo mi clase localidad con un **id** y un **nombre** de localidades. Lo cual cargo mi combobox desde la BD pasandole por parámetro el id y el nombre de la siguiente manera.. `JCombobox.additem(new Localidad(rs.setInt("Nro"), rs.setString("Nombre"));` eso lo hago cuando cargo el combo pero no se como pasárselo desde mi fila seleccionada me explico?